# jquery selector doesn't work on added tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have problem with new created element using jQuery my little script is here:

```
$('.view_button').click(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: '/devices/view_ajax',
        cache: false,
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {id: $(this).attr('data')},
        success: function(data){
            var maskHeight = $(window).height();
            var maskWidth = $(window).width() - 100;
            var body = $('#devices_wrapper');
            var div_outside =  $('<div/>', {id:'wrapper'}).appendTo(body);
            div_element =  $('<div/>', {id:'popup'}).appendTo(div_outside);
            div_element.css({position: 'relative', bottom: 0, 'z-index': 10000});
            $.each(data, function(i,v){
                if(v && i){
                    div_wrapper =  $('<div/>', {'class': 'part'}).appendTo(div_element);
                    div = document.createElement('div');
                    span = document.createElement('span');
                    $(span).html(i).appendTo(div_wrapper);
                    $(div).html(v).appendTo(div_wrapper);
                }
            });
            close_button = $('<div/>', {'class':'close_popup', text: 'X'}).appendTo(div_wrapper);

        },
        error: function(data){
            alert('error');
        }
    })
});

$('.close_popup').click(function(){
    $('#wrapper').remove();
})
```

When i click on `close_popup` nothing is executed, i think the cause of it is that `tag > close_popup` is not seen by jQuery selector if so how to add it ? Or maybe there is different my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** to attach events for those elements that are added dynamically to the DOM:

```
$(document.body).on('click','.close_popup',function(){
    $('#wrapper').remove();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `delegeate` or `on` to bind events for dynamically created elements.

```
$(document).delegate('.close_popup','click',function(){
    $('#wrapper').remove();
});
```

OR

```
$(document).on('.close_popup','click',function(){
    $('#wrapper').remove();
});
```

But it is always better to use [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 1):

```
  Try  select immediate parent which static on your html dom


$("#devices_wrapper").on("click",".close_popup",function(){

          $('#wrapper').remove();
    });
```